# String to binary, difference between constant and variable conversion

Tags: string, binary, erlang, type-conversion

Can somebody please explain me why the second statement gives a `badarg`?

Thanks

```
42> <<"hello">>.
<<"hello">>
43> Content = "hello".
"hello"
44> <<Content>>.
** exception error: bad argument
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<"hello">>` is just a special syntax to create a binary that contains the bytes in the string literal - it's syntactic sugar for `<<$h, $e, $l, $l, $o>>`, and the fact that it looks like a string (i.e., a list of characters) is just a coincidence.

If the string is in a variable, you can't insert it into the binary directly; you need to convert it explicitly:

```
ContentBinary = list_to_binary(Content),
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type <<"hello">> in the console or in a program, it is a kind of shortcut that says take the list "hello" en convert it to binary. Then the console use the pretty print format to display it.

When you define Content as a the list "hello", the syntax shortcut is no more available, and erlang is looking for a  valid type (Type= integer | float | binary | bytes | bitstring | bits | utf8 | utf16 | utf32 ) and find a list instead it is why you get this bad argument exeption.

the following entries are correct:

```
7> V1 = <<"hello">>.         
<<"hello">>
8> V2 = "hello".             
"hello"
9> V1 = list_to_binary(V2).  
<<"hello">>
```